# How do I install Debian from a live-booting-laptop

Tags: usb-drive, debian-installer

Is there a way to install Debian from a running Debian with network access?
Is so, can anybody point me to a tutorial?

#### Edit

I abandoned Windows 7 on my laptop after creating a bootable USB with Debian. I now want to install Debian. My former Windows is no longer accessible to me. Is it possible to install Debian while running Debian?

I get the install option from the USB boot, but the machine cannot find installation file on live boot USB.

I read through the U&L question [What's the easiest way to decrypt a disk partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74692/whats-the-easiest-way-to-decrypt-a-disk-partition) but I might be too much of a newbie to follow the instructions.

I have cabled network access after boot.

Comment: So you're booting the Debian live USB, which fails to run the installation program because it's corrupted? Have you tried rewriting the iso?

Comment: what exactly are you asking? ... your post is somewhat confused

Comment: I succesfully boot from live USB. I can also choose install but USB cannot be read as install CD

Comment: I have tried to clarify

Comment: I am afraid I do not have the ISO on my live boot USB,. I am not sure, though.

Comment: To do it simple, just redownload a debian install iso (using the system used to post this question) and put it again on an other USB disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make encryption passphrase easier to type**

Instead of reinstalling I opted for
[changing the passphrase](https://dradisframework.com/support/guides/customization/change_volume_passphrase.html)
on the encrypted volume:
[image]