# What is the proper way to shrink a LVM partition?

Tags: partition, lvm

I want to shrink a Linux LVM partition from 200GB to 150GB. A test is carried out with the following steps:

- Shrink a file system in a logical volume with `reszie2fs`
- Shrink the logical volume with `lvreduce`
- Delete the 200GB LVM partition with `fdisk`
- Recreate the same LVM partition, but with size a reduced of 150GB

I am able to access a test file using the above method. But, `vgdisplay` and `vgs` both reported the old size of 200GB. I think I might have missed out a `vgreduce` step after shrinking the logical volume. But, from the man page, it seems to say that `vgreduce` can only be performed on an empty physical volume. In my situation above, the whole volume group resides in one physical volume.

What is the correct way to shrink this LVM partition?

Comment: http://blog.shadypixel.com/how-to-shrink-an-lvm-volume-safely/

Comment: @slm, I am referring to the physical _partition_, not logical volume.

Comment: They're called VG & LV. Volume Group and Logical Volumes.

Comment: @slm, I am referring to shrinking a partition such as /dev/sda3 containing the VG and LVs.

Comment: I believe to reduce the VG so you can eventually shrink the partition they're on using `fdisk` you'd need to follow this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67702/how-to-reduce-volume-group-size-in-lvm

Comment: Are you just trying to learn using these tools or are you trying to get something done? I think I'd encourage you to use gparted instead of doing it in this manner.

Comment: But obviously to use `gparted` or, if available, `partitionmanager`, only **after** reducing the VG, right?

Comment: @slm, thanks for the link, `pvresize` is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're just trying to learn using these tools or are trying to get something done, in either case I think I'd encourage you to use [`gparted`](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/features.php) instead of doing it using the straight commands in this manner.

> Use GParted to resize the LVM physical volume. GParted won't let you shrink the LVM physical volume to a size smaller than what the unallocated space allows.

#### References

- [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume/196134#196134)
- [11.5. Using the LVM utility system-config-lvm](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-system-config-lvm)
- [GParted Manual](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual)

Comment: Gparted doesn't support LVM2 as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/349677/573767) and on my personal experience. It even doesn't show used space on LVM partition properly.

Comment: according to this Gparted does support most operations on LVM2: https://gparted.org/features.php

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why that comment was left. LVM 1/2 is supported.

Comment: "9.5. Using the LVM utility system-config-lvm" link is down.

Comment: @Scorpion - ty fixed